# Sqllite3 with Golang

Tags: sqlite, go

**Today, gogland download new updates and after getting updates, it shows below error message. Previously it worked fine. Please advise to solve the issue.**

```
GOROOT=/usr/local/go
GOPATH=/home/minhaj/GoLang
/usr/local/go/bin/go build -o /home/minhaj/GoLang/bin/GoLangRun -gcflags "-N -l" "-ldflags=-linkmode internal" /home/minhaj/GoLang/src/IndoorMass/IndoorMain.go
```

## command-line-arguments

```
github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3(.data.rel): unexpected R_X86_64_64 relocation for dynamic symbol close

github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3(.data.rel): unexpected R_X86_64_64 relocation for dynamic symbol access

github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3(.data.rel): unexpected R_X86_64_64 relocation for dynamic symbol getcwd

github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3(.data.rel): unexpected R_X86_64_64 relocation for dynamic symbol ftruncate64

github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3(.data.rel): unexpected R_X86_64_64 relocation for dynamic symbol fcntl

github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3(.data.rel): unexpected R_X86_64_64 relocation for dynamic symbol read

github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3(.data.rel): unexpected R_X86_64_64 relocation for dynamic symbol write

github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3(.data.rel): unexpected R_X86_64_64 relocation for dynamic symbol fchmod

github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3(.data.rel): unexpected R_X86_64_64 relocation for dynamic symbol unlink

github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3(.data.rel): unexpected R_X86_64_64 relocation for dynamic symbol mkdir

github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3(.data.rel): unexpected R_X86_64_64 relocation for dynamic symbol rmdir

github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3(.data.rel): unexpected R_X86_64_64 relocation for dynamic symbol fchown

github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3(.data.rel): unexpected R_X86_64_64 relocation for dynamic symbol geteuid

github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3(.data.rel): unexpected R_X86_64_64 relocation for dynamic symbol mmap64

github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3(.data.rel): unexpected R_X86_64_64 relocation for dynamic symbol munmap

github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3(.data.rel): unexpected R_X86_64_64 relocation for dynamic symbol mremap

github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3(.data.rel): unexpected R_X86_64_64 relocation for dynamic symbol readlink

github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3(.data.rel): unhandled relocation for close (type 42 rtype 1)

github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3(.data.rel): unhandled relocation for access (type 42 rtype 1)

github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3(.data.rel): unhandled relocation for getcwd (type 42 rtype 1)

github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3(.data.rel): relocation target stat64 not defined
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: too many errors
```

Comment: This came up https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/issues/111

Comment: I tried mentioned link, but unable to solve the issue.

Comment: Issue is fixed just by updating gogland to version Gogland-171.4424.55

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is fixed just by updating gogland to version Gogland-171.4424.55